# Stuck with 1 Peer and 0 balance

Tags: wallets, mist, rinkeby

When I start the mist Ethereum Wallet it shows Rinkeby in the top, right corner, and it goes through the node connection process; then it says it needs to sync and it is looking for peers. Because this seems to take a while, I click on the Launch Application button, and after that when I check the menu develop it shows "Main network" is checked. However, there is only 1 peer, 9 months since last block and a 0 balance. I'm positive I have a few Ethers from checking on etherscan.io.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the keystore folder in the previous Ethereum installation. I then deleted all the rest and reinstalled. In the installation process, after starting the application, Ethereum Wallet asks if one needs to install as sandbox. I guess I must answered Yes the previous time, which had installed a Rinkeby sandbox.